# Psycopg2 SQL string composition using Identifier

Tags: python, database, psycopg2

I've read many posts and the documentation but can't figure out how to properly and safely dynamically create SQL string that will work with my function that creates a query using a temp file. The function works with SQL statements not created dynamically.

```
import pandas as pd
import tempfile
from psycopg2 import sql

# connect to database
connection = psycopg2.connect(
    host="localhost",
    database="mydb",
    user="postgres",
    password='root',
)

mylist = ['ABC','DEF','GHI']

query = sql.SQL("(SELECT id FROM mydb WHERE mydb.name IN ({})").format(sql.SQL(', ').join(map(sql.Identifier, mylist)))

# function to read query from db
def read_sql_tmpfile(query):
    with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as tmpfile:
        copy_sql = "COPY ({query}) TO STDOUT WITH CSV {head}".format(
           query=(query), head="HEADER")
        cur = connection.cursor()
        cur.copy_expert(copy_sql, tmpfile)
        tmpfile.seek(0)
        df = pd.read_csv(tmpfile)
        return df

df = read_sql_tmpfile(query)
```

I get the following error:

SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "Composed"
LINE 1: COPY (Composed([SQL('(SELECT id FROM mydb WHERE mydb.name IN...

Comment: If you're going to use the `sql.SQL` class and then combine it with a regular string, that may not work so you can try using `query.as_string(connection)` to get a regular string representation of your SELECT statement. I also noticed that you `map` the values in `myslist` with `SQL.Identifier`, but the values in `mylist` are not identifiers; instead you should use `SQL.Literal` there.

Comment: Sure thing :) Best wishes with the rest of the project!